# How to deal with windows services that don't start or need recycled every now and then?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-service

A number of vendor windows services does not start in service mode or it needs recycling whenever our testing is halted.

I am able to run it as application, but it requires me to logged on the server all the time as the server logs out after timeout.

I also tried to manually create it using `SC` but does not work. The vendor solution is instead of providing a fix, they want us to upgrade the entire suit and it wont happen.

Is there any other way we can try to make this service function.

**Edit**:
  The point of the question is to figure something like hack to make the exe work and the answer which suggested me to use `srvany` helped. I was able to follow a tutorial to make it work. And I made my own windows service that periodically recycles the services I needed.

Comment: Ideas? What about "contact the vendor". It he provides a windows service and it does not start, then this is a technical support call.

Comment: I would take it up with the software vendor. Specially if your company has paid for it.

Comment: "contact the vendor" was tried and support response did not help.

Comment: Consider to olloow up with "contact a lawyer". Seriously, this is not a technical issue - they fix their stuff or you look for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use srvany, but it is not supported by Microsoft. Or a slightly better alternative to srvany, NSSM, Non-Sucking Service Manager: http://nssm.cc/usage

Obviously, the optimal situation would be to only use vendors that know how to develop services.

Comment: Thank you.. Yeah.. support was not great so I wrote an an application that restarts a service every few minutes but the one that did not start is still messed up.  I will try srvany though